# cytoscape.js: canvas refresh after batchData?

Tags: refresh, redraw, cytoscape.js

After updating node attributes using the great batchData command (these attributes are mapped to node color, size and border) the displayed network does not change until I select the nodes with my mouse.  Various attempts at `forceRender` `reset` and `fit` did not help.  So for the moment I am improvising like this:

```
cw.batchData(noa);
cw.elements("node:visible").select().unselect()
```

Which works fine, at least on a small network.

Any other advice?  Shall I send a minimal example, or a jsfiddle so this can be recreated?

Thanks!

- Paul

Answer (score 0):

I'll see if I can reproduce this on the demo page, since it seems straighforward, but please describe this issue in the tracker. https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new

Edit: I can't reproduce this on the demo page (the mapped styled get updated after cy.batchData(), so an example would definitely be worthwhile).